# How can I check an enum's value and its associated enum's value with a single case statement?

Tags: swift, enums

Please have a look at the switch statement below. I am looking for a more swifty way to perform the test; something like:

```
case let .b(other) where .x = other // This does not compile
```

Is it possible?

```
enum MyEnum {
    case a
    case b(MyOtherEnum)
}

enum MyOtherEnum {
    case x
    case y
}

func check(value: MyEnum) {
    switch value {
    case let .b(other):
        if case .x = other {
            print("Got it!")
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func check(value: MyEnum) {
    switch value {
    case .b(.x):
        print("Got it!")
    case .b(_):
        print("Not it!")
    default:
        break
    }
}

let myVar = MyEnum.b(.x)
check(value: myVar)
// prints "Got it!"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are only interested in the case `MyEnum.b(.x)` and no other
cases then you can also use `if` with a `case` pattern:

```
func check(value: MyEnum) {
    if case .b(.x) = value {
        print("Got it!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `==` not `=`:

```
case let .b(other) where .x == other
```

This works fine for me:

```
func check(value: MyEnum) {
    switch value {
    case let .b(other) where other == .x:
        print("bx")
    case let .b(other) where other == .y:
        print("by")
    default:
        break
    }
}

check(value: MyEnum.b(.x)) // prints "bx"
check(value: MyEnum.b(.y)) // prints "by"
```